# match rows having all rows returned in subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-division

Is this possible?

Query:

```
select name,id
from player
join player_ability on pid=id
where ability = (select ability
                 from player_ability
                 where player=2)
```

My subquery returns X and Y. `(select ability from player_ability where player=2)`

My main query will match all rows that contains either X **or** Y, **or** both.

How can I make sure my main query result matches both X **and** Y?

Comment: Today I was facing the same situation ... sqlite doesn't seem to have something like `in all` as in MySQL (probably that's why it's 'lite' :) and as such you have to break your query into two parts (specially if the number of results from the subquery varies, e.g. can be empty, two or ten). As per my knowledge I would first select all abilities for specific player then enumerate through returned abilities and dynamically construct final select query. If anybody has better solution I would love to learn that!

Comment: @DavidJirman You just edited the last line from "How can I make sure my main query query returns have X and Y" [sic]. I couldn't make sense of either version. "My main query will match all rows that contains either X or Y, or both" suggests that the OP's = is a typo for IN. What you both seems to want is name & id for players who have all the abilities of player 2, ie who *have (ability) matches for* all of player 2's. Ie who  *have matches for* both X and Y. But both of you have written obscurely.

Comment: @philipxy you're right, my understanding of the question is same as yours: the player returned by the main query has to have both the abilities (x and y). That's why I posted my comment since both '=' and 'IN' are returning results for either of the abilities (and thus incorrect); please feel free to edit the edit, i tried my best

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to modify your subquery as follows:

```
select name,id
from player
join player_ability on pid=id
where ability IN (select ability
    from player_ability
    where player=2
    group by ability having count(ability) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

From what you have mentioned in your question, the subquery seems be returning more than one row. In such a case, you cannot using '=' operator. You need to use 'IN' operator. If the player 2 has the abilities X and Y, IN operator will make sure that it will return rows which have the either X or Y or both the abilities. It will also return rows for other abilities which the player 2 has.

Comment: down vote for: your answer provides solution that matches either **X or Y or both** while the question seeks a solution that matches **X and Y**

Comment: @DavidJirman & Sandeep Mittal  Maybe this "answer" was really intended to correct the (undesired) query that is already in the question? Because it should have an IN not a =.